# How to generate random values from a normal distribution with specific mean in R

Tags: r

I have a book with this equation, but I am not sure how to translate this to code in R. I was wondering if someone could provide an example.

[image]

I want to generate random values from this distribution.

Comment: What do you want to do with this? Do you want to generate some random values from the distribution described by this equation? Plot its density distribution? Others? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Z.Lin sorry, I updated my question. I am curious how someone would generate random values from this distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rnorm` to generate random values:

```
set.seed(100)
mu <- 5 # or whatever your mean is
n <- 10 # the number of random values you wish to generate.

x <- rnorm(n, mean = mu) #the function's default standard deviation is already 1
x

[1] 4.497808 5.131531 4.921083 5.886785 5.116971 5.318630 4.418209 5.714533
[9] 4.174741 4.640138
```

Comment: so what is the difference between random normals and random normals conditioned on the mean? Is it just the fact that the mean does not have to be 1, but and value? So `rnorm(mean=1,n)` vs `norm(mean=x,n)` where `x` is any other mean.